# Fourier analysis of Harmonic waveforms (Electrical AC Analysis)

Tags: python, scipy, fft

I have managed to generate the wavefrom in numpy and using fundamental then 3,5, & 7 Harmonic but them I want a graph of the frequency domains which it does but is unreadable.  I should see fundamental 3,5,& 7 but it looks all merged?

I tried reading up on from [https://realpython.com/python-scipy-fft/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) and I get a bit closer to the result each time but the last bit is particular to my discipline and not based on Audio signals!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq

#generate a test signal
x = np.linspace(0, 360, num = 720, endpoint = False)

signal = 10 * np.sin(np.deg2rad(x)) + 5 * np.sin(np.deg2rad(3*x)) + 5 * np.sin(np.deg2rad(5*x)) + 11 * np.sin(np.deg2rad(7*x))

plt.plot(signal)
plt.show()

#Apply the FFT

fft = rfft(signal)

#calculate the frequencies

frequencies = rfftfreq(len(signal))

#plot the results

plt.plot(frequencies, np.abs(fft))

plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.show()
```

[image]

and the output that looks wrong:-

[image]

I tried the suggested modification by @mtrw, many thanks for replying, but this comes out:-

[image: Frequency domain chart]

To clarify what I am looking for is something like this:-
[image: Mock up of frequency domain]

Comment: If you plot your FFT result in dB does that provide something closer to your expectation: `plt.plot(frequencies, 20*np.log10(np.abs(fft)))`

Comment: Alas, no but I have editted my orignal post with an example of what I  would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1nFn.png)this link is very helpful: https://towardsdatascience.com/fourier-transform-the-practical-python-implementation-acdd32f1b96a .

For the amplitude you need to normalize the np.abs(fft).
For the frequencies, you must use the sampling rate in the rfftfreq command to get the proper results.

the code you are looking for is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq

#generate a test signal
x = np.linspace(0, 360, num = 720, endpoint = False)

signal = 10 * np.sin(np.deg2rad(x)) + 5 * np.sin(np.deg2rad(3*x)) + 5 * np.sin(np.deg2rad(5*x)) + 11 * np.sin(np.deg2rad(7*x))

sampling_rate = 720
#plt.plot(signal)
#plt.show()

#Apply the FFT

fft = rfft(signal)/(len(signal)/2)

#calculate the frequencies

frequencies = rfftfreq(len(signal), d=1/sampling_rate)

#plot the results
plt.figure(dpi=200)
plt.bar(frequencies, np.abs(fft), width=0.51, color='maroon')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim(0, 8)
#plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.show()
```